# Bootstrap conflict with PHP. Menu collapse not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having a weird issue with Bootstrap. When I call for a PHP function the collapse menu doesn't work anymore.

Here is the code I'm using.

index.html header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/override.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

included before the header a config.php which has the code:

```
require_once(DIR_FS_INCLUDES.'functions/function.php');
$db_link = re_db_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
//echo mysql_error(); 
define('DB_LINK', $db_link);
```

If I comment out the $db_link the menu start working again.

Here is the code for the $db_link

```
function re_db_connect($server = DB_SERVER, $username = DB_SERVER_USERNAME, $password = DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $database = DB_DATABASE, $link = 'db_link') {
global $$link;
if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true') {
    $$link = mysql_pconnect($server, $username, $password);
} else {
    $$link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
}
if ($$link) mysql_select_db($database);
    return $$link;
}
```

The issue with the function re_db_connect(), once again if I delete it everything works fine. I've looked at the outputted HTML and nothing seems to be out of place.

I'm not sure why PHP is effecting Bootstrap and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: PHP cannot affect bootstrap, it is your output. One is server side one is client side.

Comment: It's probably that define statement, like Tseng pointed out.  It's probably echoing out something goofy further down the line and breaking a `div` that bootstrap affects.

Comment: I've checked the web page through W3 HTML5 validator to see if there is any goofy tags throwing in there. The page was clean and successfully checked as HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

As per PHP documentation for [`define`](https://www.php.net/define) it is not recommended to use define for resources, despite being possible.

> **value**: The value of the constant; only scalar and null values are allowed.
> Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values. It is
> possible to define resource constants, however it is not recommended
> and may cause unpredictable behavior.

Depending on your code, your line above may cause a PHP error. For this you should look at the logfiles and see if there are any errors or warnings.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply, I have deleted the define and changed it to a variable in the function file called $link and then imported into all the functions that used to use that constant. through global. That didn't fix the problem as well.

Comment: What does your webserver log files say? Does it print any error which may corrupt the output, i.e. getting messages that the login failed etc.